Adding a new Web Form with Master Page causes errors BC30002 and BC30456 in my project
This is not a new project. It was originally started in VS 2019, now working in VS 2022. I have tried both environments with this and still get the same errors.
This is a ASP.NET/VB.NET application. It was working fine, and I had added forms in recent weeks. But now all of a sudden I get the following errors when I try adding a web form called FGSales.aspx.
Errors
BC30002 Type 'Global.ProductionApp17.FGSale' is not defined.
BC30456 'Context' is not a member of 'fgsale_aspx'.
enter image description here
I have gone back to prior versions of my code base, as well as tried VS 2019 but these errors continue to appear when I add a Web Form with my Master Page.
I have tried a complete rebuild, I have rebooted, and I have done all the VS.NET updates.

Visual Studio's "Output" tab may show errors in a way that's easier to post than posting screen-dumps. If not, it's best to paste text, that can be searched later, than images. Can you post an excerpt of the code that is getting these three errors reported against it? I realise that they're all reported against line 1 of the ASP.

Can you add a form with different name? Looks so far like a naming conflict.  You can't create a form with same as existing public classes

Create a new project to see if you can reproduce the issue to check if the error is specific to your project or related to Visual Studio.

I'm using vs2022, version 17.9.6 (latest version).
I am freely able to add a webform with master page.
Hence this works for me:

I would check if you have the webforms workflows installed. These workflows are required to add web forms.
So, from tools->Get Tools and features.
Then make sure the webforms support and workflows are installed.
These:

And also, these further down:

So, the workflows for webform's development are not installed by default, but once the above additional parts are installed, then adding a webform, or even a webform + master page looks to work just fine.
You don't mention if this is a asp.net web site, or a asp.net web site "application".  So, how you are opening the project matters.
A web site is opened by using file->Open web site, and you browse to the project folder (this option means no .sln project file is used or opened by you).
If this is a asp.net web site "application", then you use file->open project, and choose the .sln file from folder for that given project.
I would as a test create a brand-new project, and see if that works. If the new project allows adding of web pages, then I suspect that some code or other file damage has occurred to the one project.
In other words, do all projects not allow adding of a master + child page pair, or is this issue limited to the one project, and adding a master + child page to other projects works just fine.
